# When I try to use a variable in an if() it says that I am using an unassigned variable

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
string x1;                  
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action (() => x1 = lbl1.Content.ToString()));
```

(I did this because I'm using threads)
(Then when I try to use it in an if)

```
if(x1 == "X"){}
```

(I get an error saying that I am using an unassigned variable)

Can someone tell me why is this happening please?

Comment: Since you assign x1 in a different thread it mayhaps that in the main thread x1 is unassigned. That's why the compiler warns you

Comment: Also see [Compiler Error CS0165 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y7h161d.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign x1 like this

```
string x1;                  
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action (() => x1 = lbl1.Content.ToString()));
```

You are assigning x1 on a different thread but the compiler can't detect that your variable is assigned.

Try to set a default value for x1, that should fix the issue

```
String x1 = "";
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

See:

```
  string x1; // <- Just declared, not assigned

  // x1 is assigned, but in the different thread
  Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action (() => x1 = lbl1.Content.ToString()));

  // it may occure, that the diffrent thread hasn't finished yet, and 
  // x1 is still unassigned; that's why the compiler shows the warning
  if(x1 == "X"){}
```

In some cases, however, it's *the compiler* that can't just *trace the assignment*, e.g.

```
  String x1;

  Action f = 
    () => { x1 = "X"; };

  f(); // <- x1 will be assigned here

  // Compiler erroneously warns here that x1 is unassigned,
  // but x1 is assigned  
  if (x1 == "X")
```

Comment: Given that Dispatcher.Invoke is a blocking (synchronous) call. Is it actually possible or is it just not known to the compiler?

Comment: @James Barrass: yes, if the assignment is a tricky one you can have an erroneous warning from the compiler; see my edit

Answer (score 1):

From [`Compiler Error CS0165`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y7h161d.aspx)

> C# compiler does not allow the use of uninitialized variables. If the
>   compiler detects the use of a variable that might not have been
>   initialized, it generates compiler error

You declared your `x1` variable but you didn't initialize it. Might need to initialize it like;

```
string x1 = "";
```

or

```
string x1 = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't realize that you are assigning x1, since this isn't a straight forward assignment.
Therefore just change this line:

```
string x1 = null; // or assign a different default value
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you assign `x1` in a different thread  that why in the main thread `x1` is unassigned

you can correct it by assigning `null` to `x1` at the time of declaration of `x1`

```
string x=null;
```

Answer (score 0):

think about it, you are using multi threads.

1. On thread A you declare `x1`.
2. On thread A you are trying to use `x1`.
3. On thread B you assign `x1`.

Now, what will be the order of event? will it be `1 > 3> 2`? why should the compiler assume that?
If it will be `1 >2 >3` it means you are attempting to use `x1` before it was assigned, and this is what the compiler is complaining about.